# Executing a PHP file using Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Still grasping Ajax, so I beg your patience. I am trying to run a php file from within javascript using an ajax call with the help of jQuery. I do not need to GET / POST any data, I just intent the PHP code to be executed and the message 'hello world' logged to the console (I intend to use this in a button with an onclick() function). The only thing that gets logged is the "success" message. I want the PHP code to execute without leaving the current page, but I think I may be missing how AJAX works. Or perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this. Thanks for helping out.

PS: I can see the resource "ajax.php" is being loaded as a XHR, by using Safari's web developer tools.

Content of the index file that calls ajax.php is:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url : 'action/ajax.php',
  type : 'POST',
  success : function (result) {
    console.log ('success');
  },
  error : function () {
    console.log ('error');
  }
});
</script>
```

Content of ajax.php is:

```
<?php
echo '<script>console.log("hello world");</script>';
?>
```

Comment: `echo 'hello world';` for php and `console.log(result);` for javascript.

Comment: Basically what you are trying to achieve is opening an alert using ajax. Its better you run some PHP code you will find result in success section

Comment: Inside the ajax success method, result is the variable that holds the information returned from ajax.php.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Appreciate that you are taking initiative to learn PHP, jQuery and AJAX.

Just some modifications and you are on track:

**Javascript (jQuery):**

```
<script>
   $.ajax({

     url : 'action/ajax.php',
     type : 'POST',
     success : function (result) {
        console.log (result); // Here, you need to use response by PHP file.
     },
     error : function () {
        console.log ('error');
     }

   });
</script>
```

**Content of ajax.php is:**

```
<?php
    //echo '<script>console.log("hello world");</script>';
    // Change above line to:
    echo "hello world";
?>
```

Comment: i am getting CORS policy blocking when i am trying to access the file.. Been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
i am using absolute path.. not relative path bcz i am calling the PHP file from Fitnesse application.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is stored in callback function

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
  url : 'action/ajax.php',
type : 'POST',
 success : function (result) {
 //this is where you need to call your data which is result and not success
 console.log (result);
 },
error : function () {
 console.log ('error');
 }
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to execute the returned javascript if you want it to run

```
success : function (result) {
    eval(result); //run the result code
    console.log ('success');
},
```

Content of ajax.php will now be:

```
<?php
   echo 'console.log("hello world")';
?>
```

But then you nead clean JS without the `script` tag

Comment: Instead of using eval, you could simply just use `$.getScript('script.js')` since jQuery is used anyways.

Comment: @EJTH still its not all the way wrong. it is an feasible solution, good effort zedd +1 for you buddy

Comment: Except that his answer wouldn't work for the question. And `eval` is pretty much always the wrong answer.